# JfreeChart Error in Linux/Unix environment

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am getting this error in the Linux environment while displaying 3D pie charts on the web browser. It works perfectly fine in the windows environment.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
Could not initialize class org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart
at org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory.createPieChart3D(ChartFactory.java:763)
```

---

I have set the system property System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true"); in my java code.
On checking the property, it has been set to true successfully.
But still i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect  your Linux server is running headless. See [*Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html), as well as this related forum [thread](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1012&hilit=X11+DISPLAY+BufferedImage).

Comment: See also [`createPieChart3D()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.736), and check the servlet container's class path.