# Server-side/ non-interactive rendering of Charts to image files from JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

How does one  programmatically render image files from JFreeChart .  I have code for ChartPanel: is it possible to render directly to an image - without creating AWT/GUI components?

```
val chart = ..  // Imagine code to generate chart data here..
val panel = new ChartPanel(chart)
panel.renderToImage() // replace this with logic to save image file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of the [`ChartUtilities`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartUtilities.html) methods, such as `writeChartAsJPEG()` or `writeChartAsPNG()`, that can write to a `java.io.OutputStream`; or `saveChartAsJPEG()` or `saveChartAsPNG()`, that can write to a `java.io.File`. Some examples are seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjfreechart%5D%20ChartUtilities.writeChartAs*) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjfreechart%5D%20ChartUtilities.saveChartAs*). For example,

```
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File("chart.png"), chart, width, height);
```

You'll also want to look into headless mode, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7401312/230513).